# AMQP_MANDATORY flag not working in PHP (w/ RabbitMQ)

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

When publishing a message to `RabbitMQ` in `PHP`, the `AMQPExchange->publish` method returns `true` even if the exchange is not found. I am setting the `AMQP_MANDATORY` flag. Here is the code:

```
$myExchange->publish($myMessage, $myRoutingKey, AMQP_MANDATORY, $myOptions);
```

I know I am using the method in a valid way, since it works, but if I feed it a non-existent exchange or queue, it still returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mandatory, like immediate, doesn't fail the publish action but instead returns the message, on the return channel of your AMQP client. So you need to check if messages have been returned to find out about issues with this mandatory publication.

Related: See this comment on `AMQPExchange::publish`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpexchange.publish.php#106987

Comment: How can I read from that channel?  The Exchange is constructed with a channel $channel which is constructed with a connection $connection.

Comment: Usually this is done by registering a listener on the channel: http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#returning I do not know how/if this is feasible with the PHP library.